# AC source in parallel with resistor problem

Tags: resistors, ac

For an AC source of for example +-12 V, can a connected resistor at any instant, have 24 V across it?

Because my textbook has a problem in it involving such a source and says (hint: consider the source as a 24 V battery)and I am trying to make sense of why this is valid.

Edit: no there is nothing at all. Just a source connected in parallel to a resistor and it's asking me to calculate the minimum resistor value if the resistor is valued at 0.25 W. The source provides a voltage of +-12 V and to calculate the resistance you would have to take the source as being equivalent to a 24 V source (according to book) then (24^2)/0.25=Minimum resistor value.

I just don't understand why you can take the value as 24 V.

Comment: You must give more information / context for your question. If it's homework, post the work done about it.

Comment: Yes, if there are any components which create a phase shift.  But how is your 24v battery a 12v AC source, unless you are using it to power a synthesizer?

Comment: Put the question in the body where it belongs.  The title is supposed to give us a quick idea what the question is about.  Using the title as the only place to ask the question is annoying.

Comment: @ChrisStratton It isn't a 12 V battery but for the purpose of the problem the book is saying you can assume it is.

Comment: @MartinPetrei I have done so.

Comment: If the source provides +-12 V, then the difference is 24 V.  +-12 V does not mean there is a 12 V lead and a ground one, it means there is a +12 V lead, a -12 V lead, and a ground in between (which may or may not be externally exposed).  Ie, not one 12 V battery, but two.

Comment: @MartinPetrei The problem is there isn't one. The problem nowhere states AC source but I assumed it was one because I wasn't familiar with the other setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess but this question may be referring to a split supply e.g. from a centre tapped secondary of a transformer. It is very difficult to give a definitive answer to questions without the full background.

[image]